# Latitude, Longitude Grabber

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, google-geocoding-api

What I would like to do is create app where when anyone clicks on the map object and two fields get filled with latitude and longitude at every click. Is there sample code of Google Maps V3 JavaScript API (Geocoding API) somewhere out there that does something like that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this with [google.maps.event'](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#event) LatLng property:

Something like this would show how it works.  Here is a [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/duNaX/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
       alert('Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' Lng: ' + event.latLng.lng());
});
```

Where map is your google map object.  Yes the example is in V2 i think, and if you would like to create a marker on click you can simply create it within the click callback function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete code for version 2 which i had been using for a long time and i have published in the site.

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v2/get-lattitude-longitude-onmouseover-and-onmouseclick-google-map-v2.htm

just click view source code from your browser and copy save the contents. it will work perfectly. only thing is you need to change the map api key.

**Here is the code for google map version 3**

http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/get-lattitude-longitude-onclick-and-onmouseover-google-map-v3.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
function onload()
{
 var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
zoom: 14,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
disableDefaultUI: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
       alert('Lat: ' + event.latLng.lat() + ' and Longitude is: ' + event.latLng.lng());

}
```

After loading code you can write this code to get latitude and longitude of fix points.
please try

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = [google map];

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (mouseEvent) {
    alert(mouseEvent.latLng.toUrlValue());
});
```