# Generate latitude and longitude on click in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there any tutorial on how can I get latitude and longitude whenever a user click a specific place in the maps? Thanks! I'm using Google Maps.

Comment: See this [post for a way to get it using the Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571641/latitude-longitude-grabber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example will shows exactly how to generate lat and long on mouse events

[Get lattitude and longitude onmouseover and onclick event in google map](http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v2/get-lattitude-longitude-onmouseover-and-onmouseclick-google-map-v2.htm)