# how to get lat long on mouse pointer in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to bring latitude and longitude of google maps on mouse pointer in a google map web application, has any one tried this before ? if yes, please show me the way to achieve this. I am searching this from couple of days and ended up with empty handed.

Regards,
Beginner in UI.

Comment: This question has been answered on SO many times before. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572076/4283301), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247121/4283301), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247006/get-latitude-and-longitude-on-click-event-from-google-map) for more information. Here's [a tutorial](http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v2/get-lattitude-longitude-onmouseover-and-onmouseclick-google-map-v2.htm) linked to by one of those answers.

Comment: I just searched Google and found this:
http://vikku.info/programming/google-maps-v3/get-lattitude-longitude-onclick-and-onmouseover-google-map-v3.htm

Comment: thanks for the response @shawnt00, currently my app has the feature you mentioned in the link(which is eating up some space). I was looking at something like this in the below link.

http://mapshup.com/projects/mapshup/2.5/index.html#ezpgxczbzury:3

(Lat Long is displayed on the tip of mouse pointer)

Comment: thanks for the response @razi shaban, currently my app has the feature you mentioned in the link(which is eating up some space). I was looking at something like this in the below link. mapshup.com/projects/mapshup/2.5/index.html#ezpgxczbzury:3 (Lat Long is displayed on the tip of mouse pointer)